# Use an array list depend on integer data

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio

I have 3 arrays of integer for example:

```
int[] l1 = {1,2,3};
int[] l2 = {4,5,6};
int[] l3 = {7,8,9};
```

and I have an integer witch shows me a number between 1 to 3 , I want know how to relate this number to arrays I mean if it was 2 then chose the second array to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2D-Array to do that;

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice = 2;
        int[] l1 = {1,2,3};
        int[] l2 = {4,5,6};
        int[] l3 = {7,8,9};
        int[][] toChoose = new int[3][];
        toChoose[0] = l1;
        toChoose[1] = l2;
        toChoose[2] = l3;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toChoose[1]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**If** I understood you correctly, one option might be to have a multidimensional array along the following lines:

```
    int[][] array = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};

    int[] subArray = array[2];

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subArray));
```